# MySQL - Order By exact match at the end

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this

```
ID    SPORT
1     Cricket
2     Football
3     Other
4     Racing
```

How can I get this list order by `SPORT` but still I get 'Other' at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use multiple values in the order by , the first clause will make the Other to appear at the end

```
SELECT ID, SPORT
FROM Table1
ORDER BY SPORT='Other' , SPORT
```

Comment: All is also working.

SELECT *
FROM Table1
ORDER BY SPORT='Other' , SPORT    Could you please explain this to me.

Comment: @PradyumnShrivastava, the statement SPORT='Other` will return 0 when SPORT is not other, as Ascending is the default sort order, all sports will come first then Other will come at the last.